# Google Apps Scripts loop opening url

Tags: loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to coding and I would like to be able to take the below and do 2 possible things.

1. loop it as to where I can have 1 button run both urls.
2. IF possible open the new tab either in the background or have it close itself after so many seconds.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
> function UpdateRed() {
  var score = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('CELL_VALUE').getValue();
  const url = 'hXXp://URL/RedScore='; 
  const link = `<a href="${url+score}" target="_blank"></a>`;
  const script = `<script>document.querySelector('a').click();google.script.host.close();</script>`;
  const html = link + script;
  const htmlContent = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html)
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
    .setHeight(1)
    .setWidth(1);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlContent,'Updating Red Score');
}


function UpdateBlue() {
  var score = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('CELL_VALUE').getValue();
  const url = 'hXXp://URL/BlueScore=';
  const link = `<a href="${url+score}" target="_blank"></a>`;
  const script = `<script>document.querySelector('a').click();google.script.host.close();</script>`;
  const html = link + script;
  const htmlContent = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html)
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
    .setHeight(1)
    .setWidth(1);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlContent,'Updating Blue Score');
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

#### Looping through the colors

```
function UpdateAll() {
  const cellValue = { 'Red': "E17", "Blue": "C17" }
  const script = `<script>document.querySelector('a').click();google.script.host.close();</script>`;
  ["Red", "Blue"].forEach(e => {
    let url = `hXXp://URL/=${e}Score`;
    const score = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(cellValue[e]).getValue();
    let link = `<a href="${url + score}" target="_blank"></a>`
    let html = link + script;
    let htmlContent = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME).setHeight(1).setWidth(1);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlContent, 'Updating ${e} Score');
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much... I think the one thing I misled is that the 'CELL_VALUE' is different for red and blue.. Will this account for those 2 different cells or do I need to add another constant or variable

 
`<code>
    const rscore = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('E17:F19').getValue(); 
    const bscore = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('C17:D19').getValue();
</code>`

Comment: Using getValue() on that range really only gets the the value of E17 and C17,  Is that really what you wish?